# my location marker on leaflet map don't appear when the map has other markers or routes

Tags: leaflet

I'm working to a GIS project using ionic
and I select leaflet as a map
but i have some problems to solve

in my app i want to find the rout between my location and other point , but the when a get the route and click to give me my location i don't get the circle marker

and when i launch the app - the map is empty -and click to give me my location , i get the blue circle marker normally

this is the image when the map is empty
[image: the circle marker added normally]

and this when i get the route
[image: when i create a marker or route nothing added]

Comment: Provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: excuse me, because i have bad English .
I think now the problem is clear